# Application cannot call .chm file unless help topic ID numbers are incremented by 1

Tags: c#, wpf, chm

I am a help developer. My team submitted a .chm for a new C# application. The software developer could not get context-sensitive help to appear. Finally he discovered that if he put in the help IDs we gave him that we had defined in our help authoring tool, Author-it, the help would not work, but if he added 1 to the help ID for a topic and put that in the code, then the help would appear. For example, if we told him the help ID was 37182,and he put that in the code, help would not appear at all when invoked from the app, but if he put 37183 in the code, the correct help (that is, the help from our topic 37182) would appear.

The software developers insist that according to their testing the problem is on the help developers' end, but it is a bit hard to understand how this could be an Author-it problem. If anything on our end, I think it would have to be an MS HTML Help Compiler problem (Author-it is a database for single-sourcing; it calls hhc.exe to generate the actual help). But we've never had problems with the help/app connection using these tools before, so I still think the problem might be on the other end. Either way, even though there is a workaround (add 1 to all the help IDs!) we have to be able to fix this.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening? The application is a WPF application, if that matters.

Thank you very much - Sandy

Comment: Note that the problem seems to be answered already by Michele, but in such cases an easy test can show you whose side the problem is on. (generation or consumption) This is by done by decompiling the CHM with one of the many free tools.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting here the solution provided by our Support team.

The reason for the behaviour is that you've changed the Topic ID Offset from 0 to 1 on the Help > Linking Tab of the Book object.

Setting it back to 0 will prevent the context ID's from being increased by 1.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: THE FOLLOWING IS MORE OF A COMMENT THAN AN ANSWER - only posting as an answer because it is too long for a comment!*

I would strongly recommend to build a minimum sample WPF application - some "Hello World"-type of application plus an Author-It based help file (.chm) which shows this problem.

Send that including the respective Author-It-Database and all version-information (like help compiler version etc.) to the support staff of Author-It.

If they can reproduce it then I would expect that they will come up with some sort of workaround/fix...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer at Author-it. I believe this is probably caused by the "Topic ID Offset" property. To change this property:

1. Right click on your Book
2. Select Properties from the context menu
3. Help
4. Linking
5. Topic ID Offset is probably 1, change it to 0

Save the Book and republish your CHM file.

http://kc.author-it.com/#b45755t1169n82756